# ¿Cómo almacenar datos especificos de una matriz a un arreglo en Java?

Tags: java

Me encuentro realizando un ejercicio que consiste de reconocer números menores de cada fila, luego de ello el resultado (los números menores encontrados) deben ir a un arreglo e mostrar el arreglo. Hasta ahora solamente he llegado hasta el punto de reconocer los números menores...

A continuación mi código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Variables
    int matriz[][], N,M;
    //Datos a ingresar
    System.out.print("Ingrese el tamaño de filas de la matriz: ");
    N = lectura.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Ingrese el tamaño de columnas de la matriz: ");
    M = lectura.nextInt();
    matriz = new int[N][M];
   //Proceso
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<M; j++){
            System.out.print("Ingrese el valor para A["+i+"]["+j+"] = ");
            matriz[i][j] = lectura.nextInt();
        }
    }
    ImprimirMatriz("Los datos de la matriz son: ",matriz,N,M);
    //Variables de número menor
    int menor = 0;
    int numero = 0;
    //Variables de posición
    int nFilas = matriz[0].length;
    int nColumnas = matriz.length;
    //Lógica para encontrar los números menores de las filas
    for (int x = 0; x < nColumnas; x++) {
        menor = matriz[x][0];

        for (int y = 0; y < nFilas; y++) {
            numero = matriz[x][y];
            if (numero < menor)
                menor = numero;
        }
        System.out.println("El número menor de la fila " + (x + 1) + " es: " + menor);
    }
    //Almacenar resultado en un arreglo
    //¿?
}
public static void ImprimirMatriz(String mensaje, int A[][], int N, int M){
    System.out.println("\n"+mensaje+"\n");
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<M; j++){
            System.out.print("\t"+A[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Agradezco su apoyo. ♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la cantidad de valores menor según tu código será igual a `N` numero de filas , entonces se debe declarar el array que guardara los números menores con ese dato.

```
int [] menores=new int[N];
```

ahora para guardar los números menores en el array puedes apoyarte de una variable de tipo `int` para iterar el array y guardar los valores obtenidos

```
    int [] menores=new int[N];
        for (int x = 0; x < nColumnas; x++) {
            menor = matriz[x][0];
    
            for (int y = 0; y < nFilas; y++) {
                numero = matriz[x][y];
                if (numero < menor)
                    menor = numero;
                   
            }
    //1ero guardamos el primer menor obtenido en la posicion 0 del array
            menores[aux]=menor;
   //aumentamos en +1 el indice para guardar el siguiente
            aux++;
            System.out.println("El número menor de la fila " + (x + 1) + " es: " + menor);
            
        }
        //Almacenar resultado en un arreglo
        //¿?
        //mostramos el array obtenido 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(menores));
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Disculpa, a qué te efieres con aux++?

Comment: Solo nombre la variable ,puedes darle el nombre que quieras solo que sea diferente a una variable en uso, al poner aux++ ,significa que la variable empezará con el número con el que fue declarado en este caso 0 y al encontrarse dentro de un for aumentará en 1 por cada iteración  similar a x++  y ++ ,si N es 3 Array menores será de tamaño 3 y aux será el índice que ira de 0 1 2 guardando correctamente los 3 números menores ;)